# C++ protobuf can't deserialize message

Tags: c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

I encountered a problem in protobuf with deserialize message in c++.
here is  proto message definition:

```
syntax="proto3";
message my_message{
int32 flag=1;
sign_detail sdetail=2;
}


message sign_detail{
string usr_id=1;
string usr_nickname=2;
int32 phone_num=3;
string usr_sex=4;
string email=5;
string password=6;
}
```

then i receive a socket and put it in buf:

```
   my_message recver;
   int n=recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE, 0);
   printf("%s\n", buf);
   recver.ParseFromArray(buf, n);
   cout<<"recver:"<<recver.flag();
```

but i get this:

```
flag: 2
sdetail {
  phone_num: 123
  email: "123"
  password: "123"
 }

recver:0
```

recver is empty,why?

Comment: Are you sure `int n=recv(connfd, buf, MAXLINE, 0);` already received the whole message?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  yes what i send is what i recived